# Write This Query in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, str-to-date

I need a little assistance. I need this query

```
SELECT *, STR_TO_DATE( end_date,  "%d/%m/%Y" ) AS DATE
FROM  `resume_experience` 
WHERE  `resume_id` =1
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

to be written in codeigniter active record format. This is what I wrote.

```
$result = $this->db->select('*,STR_TO_DATE(end_date,%d/%m/%Y) AS DATE')
            ->from('resume_experience')
            ->order_by('DATE', "desc")
            ->where($where)
            ->get()
            ->result_array();
    return $result;
```

It is giving me the following error.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`resume_experience`) WHERE `resume_id` = '1' ORDER BY `DATE` desc' at line 2

```
SELECT *, STR_TO_DATE(end_date, `%d/%m/%Y)` AS DATE FROM (`resume_experience`) WHERE `resume_id` = '1' ORDER BY `DATE` desc
```

Any help would highly be appreciated.

Thanks and Waiting,

Ahmad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass second parameter as `FALSE` in `select()` so it will not quote the bacticks for `STR_TO_DATE(end_date,%d/%m/%Y) AS DATE`

```
$this->db->select("*,STR_TO_DATE(end_date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS DATE",FALSE)
```

[See active record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Answer (score 0):

[`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) requires quotes around the format string:

```
$this->db->select('*,STR_TO_DATE(end_date,"%d/%m/%Y") AS DATE')
```